# Can i setup iOS and android builds in AWS?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, build

I need to build iOS and android packages for this I'm using xCode And android studio
my question is, can it be done automatically remotely using AWS service of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

Possible for Android

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/automatically-build-your-android-app-with-aws-codebuild/

For iOS, you are better off with automating the builds using CodePipeline and Jenkins.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-and-testing-ios-and-ipados-apps-with-aws-devops-and-mobile-services/

Comment: i learn that android do not need special stuff it can be built via command line in simple Linux